# Wordpress, searching custom post types in admin returning multiple post types

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 3 custom post types, all appear to have been registered okay.
They are called 'performer', 'event' and 'venue' (it's a music website)

But... in WP admin, when I list my "All performers" and do a search, the results are including all three custom post types.

Curiously the total count is correct, but the results shown include all custom post types.

Further, when I do a second search, directly after the first, I get an invalid post type error. In the query string, at this point, post_type=Array which I am guessing why.

Rather than copy lots of code, here is the register_post_type for performers, perhaps I am missing something? **[edit] full code provided as requested...**

Would appreciate any and all help!!

function my_custom_post_performer() {

```
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Performers', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Performer', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Performer' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Performer' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Performer' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Performers' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Performer' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Performers' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No performers found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No performers found in the Trash' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Performers'
);
$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Holds our performers and performer specific data',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    'has_archive'   => true,
);
register_post_type( 'performer', $args );
```

}

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_performer' );

function my_updated_performer_messages( $messages ) {
global $post, $post_ID;
$messages['performer'] = array(
    0 => '', 
    1 => sprintf( __('Performer updated. <a href="%s">View performer</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
    2 => __('Custom field updated.'),
    3 => __('Custom field deleted.'),
    4 => __('Performer updated.'),
    5 => isset($_GET['revision']) ? sprintf( __('Performer restored to revision from %s'), wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
    6 => sprintf( __('Performer published. <a href="%s">View performer</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
    7 => __('Performer saved.'),
    8 => sprintf( __('Performer submitted. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview performer</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
    9 => sprintf( __('Performer scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>. <a target="_blank" href="%2$s">Preview performer</a>'), date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i' ), strtotime( $post->post_date ) ), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
    10 => sprintf( __('Performer draft updated. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview performer</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
);
return $messages;
```

}

```
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'my_updated_performer_messages' );

function performer_info_box() {
add_meta_box( 
    'performer_info_box',
    __( 'Performer Info', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
    'performer_info_box_content',
    'performer',
    'side',
    'high'
);
```

}

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'performer_info_box' );

function performer_info_box_content( $post ) {
global $wpdb;
wp_nonce_field( 'performer_info_box_content', 'performer_info_box_content_nonce' );
echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;font-weight:bold">Owner</div>';
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $post->post_author );
$user_email = ($user) ? $user->user_email : '';
echo '<input id="performer_users" name="owner_email" value="'.$user_email.'">';

echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;font-weight:bold">Website</div>';
echo '<input type="text" id="performer_website" name="performer_website" placeholder="www.example.com" value="'.get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'performer_website', true ).'" />';

echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;font-weight:bold">Email</div>';
echo '<input type="text" id="performer_email" name="performer_email" placeholder="info@example.com" value="'.get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'performer_email', true ).'" />';

echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;font-weight:bold">Twitter</div>';
echo '<input type="text" id="performer_twitter" name="performer_twitter" placeholder="@example" value="'.get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'performer_twitter', true ).'" />';

echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;font-weight:bold">Facebook</div>';
echo '<input type="text" id="performer_facebook" name="performer_facebook" placeholder="www.facebook.com/example" value="'.get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'performer_facebook', true ).'" />';

echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;font-weight:bold">MySpace</div>';
echo '<input type="text" id="performer_myspace" name="performer_myspace" placeholder="www.example.com" value="'.get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'performer_myspace', true ).'" />';
```

}

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'performer_info_box_save' );

function performer_info_box_save( $post_id ) {

if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
return;

if ( !isset($_POST['performer_info_box_content_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['performer_info_box_content_nonce'], 'performer_info_box_content' ) )
return;

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'performer_website', $_POST['performer_website'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'performer_email', $_POST['performer_email'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'performer_twitter', $_POST['performer_twitter'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'performer_facebook', $_POST['performer_facebook'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'performer_myspace', $_POST['performer_myspace'] );
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $_POST['owner_email'] );
if ($user) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "UPDATE ".$wpdb->base_prefix."posts SET post_author = %d WHERE ID = %d";
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($sql, $user->ID, $post_id));
}
```

}

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'performer_columns_head');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'performer_columns_content', 10, 2);

function performer_columns_head($defaults) {
global $post;
if ($post->post_type == 'performer') {
    $defaults['col_performer_owner_name'] = 'Owner';
    $defaults['col_performer_website'] = 'Website';
}
return $defaults;
```

}

```
function performer_columns_content($column_name, $post_ID) {
if ($column_name == 'col_performer_owner_name') {
    $post = get_post($post_ID); 
    if ($post) {
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $post->post_author );
        if ($user)
            echo '<a href="mailto:'.$user->user_email.'">'.$user->display_name.'</a>';
    }
}
if ($column_name == 'col_performer_website') {
    $post = get_post($post_ID); 
    $www = $post->performer_website;
    if ($www) {
        if (strpos($www, 'http') === FALSE) $www = 'http://'.$www;
        echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$www.'">'.$www.'</a>';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add your code that handles `post_type`, so I can help

Comment: Thank you Hüseyin, this will be lengthy, but probably of more use. Here is all the code that creates and handles the post type:

Comment: Sorry - hit return too quick! Here it is...

Comment: Ok, too long for a comment reply, I'll edit the original post.

Comment: Done, original post edited! ;)

Comment: There is lot's of logic here. In my opinion, you cannot override original wp listing functionality. If you are not developing an plugin, I suggest you to use this plugin. http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/. This will provides you create custom types, manage them, and listing.

Comment: Yes, I didn't really want to post a lot of code ;)

Comment: It is part of a plugin, which has 3 custom post types, just that all three bring back results from all of them, not just the one you are looking at...

Comment: All based on tutorials on creating a custom post type - would all work lovely if I didn't have 3 of them with this problem... ;)